Why won't my SvelteKit code run on page load?
I've built many pages that run fine but whenever I put this code in a file it never runs. It doesn't delete the cookie, and I don't get redirected.
I've tried putting the code just in +page.ts, I've tried putting it in +page.server.ts nothing will run this code on page load.
Currently I have it in +page.server.ts like:
import {redirect} from "@sveltejs/kit";

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export const load = (async ({ cookies }) => {
    cookies.delete('session', { path: '/' });
    redirect(300, '/')
})

Is there a special way I need to wrap this?

This is related to routing, you probably should show: 1. The directory and file structure. 2. How the browser is routed to whatever route is supposed to remove the cookie.

@brunnerh Hyperlink or direct visit, neither work. My folder structure is pretty much the standard. In src theres logout/+page.server.ts as mentioned in my question

The cookie deletion code should work given the correct file directory and file paths, but the redirect is probably broken as the code 300 is for "multiple choices". 302 ("found") would be better.

I'm not sure what this answer is meant to accomplish. Status code is regardless here. Cookie is never deleted. The event never even fires.

Unless you give a minimal reproducible example there is nothing else to do. It does not reproduce. (And there are people who would conclude from a redirect not happening that the code did not run.)
